# Creating Vaadin 6 maven project

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin6

I am trying to create vaadin 6 maven project using the following cmd :
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=6.8.11 -Darchetype.properties=generate.properties  -DgroupId=com.example.cem -DartifactId=test

But it fails with :
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project cem: The defined artifact is not an archetype

when I try to change archetypeVersion to 7.6.4 a vaadin project created correctly .

what is the wrong with vaadin 6 here?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that pops into my mind is that we probably never have defined maven archetype for Vaadin 6. Maven support was introduced in later Vaadin 7 versions (ref https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-7-3-7-and-new-maven-archetypes).

But probably you can do it by creating Vaadin 7 project first and then change dependencies to Vaadin 6.